# Linq and String.Compare - the left hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write the following LINQ query...

```
string userSearch = textBoxSearchUserInput.Text;
                //LINQ query for Member name search
                var MemberNameSearch =
                    from member in context.Members 
                    where String.Compare(userSearch, member.MemberLastName, true) = 0
                        select member;
```

But I'm getting the error message in the title.

What I'm trying to achieve, comparing two strings while ignoring the case

Thanks

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. Please vote to close.

Answer (score 3):

```
where String.Compare(userSearch, member.MemberLastName, true) == 0
```

To compare you need to use `==`

Comment: Forgot to add ,I need to compare while ignoring case, I'm not able to use toLower() on member.memberId

Comment: Is that integer?

Comment: of course, sometimes it just takes someone else to point it out... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
String.Equals(userSearch, member.MemberLastName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change it

```
where String.Compare(userSearch, member.MemberLastName, true) = 0
```

To

```
where String.Compare(userSearch, member.MemberLastName, true) == 0
```